# Spotify app - preview 10 seconds of track then skip

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spotify

I'm making a Spotify app, which imports playlists, and then gives you the option of previewing the playlist, so you'd be able to press a play button, which would work through the playlist, playing 10 seconds of a track then skipping to the next

I've got the playlist integration sorted, but am struggling to know where to start on this preview button, any ideas?

EDIT:

Should have been more specific

I wanted to preview the last 30 seconds of a track, so would need to find the duration (which is where my problem lies) bring it back 30 seconds and then play 10 seconds before skipping

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this or am I misunderstanding?

```
function onPlayButtonClick() {
  playTheTrack();
  setTimeOut(playNextTrack, 10000);
}
```

Or recursively:

```
function playTrack(trackNumber) {
    stopCurrentTrack();
    playThisTrack();

    setTimeOut(function() {
        playTrack(++trackNumber);
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: awesome, that works, I should have been more specific but wrote this quickly - I wanted to preview the last 30 seconds of a track, so would need to find the duration (which is where my problem lies) bring it back 30 seconds and then play 10 seconds before skipping - hope that makes sense, thanks for your help

Comment: the api for playback is still in development but you should be able to use position - http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/f19ff300f8.html

Comment: have you done any implementation of the api to do the playback yet?

Comment: currently I've just set up the Kitchen Sink app found here - https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink - I'm creating an app mainly for learning purposes and to maybe eventually create some kind of voting system for my works playlist to stop bickering over what's getting played

Comment: so any help would be much appreciated!